# Tooptip not working in button of another program

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm in the process of creating a tooltip for a button 'connect' within a program such as RDP:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <commctrl.h>

#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    HWND hwndParent = FindWindow(L"#32770", L"Remote Desktop Connection");
    HWND hwndTool = GetDlgItem(hwndParent, 5);  //Button Connect
    if (!hwndParent && !hwndTool)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed ", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(0);
    }
 
    HWND hwndTip = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        TOOLTIPS_CLASS,
        NULL,
        TTS_NOPREFIX | TTS_ALWAYSTIP,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        hwndParent,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );

    if (!hwndTip) {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Failed to create tooltip!", L"Error", MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(0);
    }

    TOOLINFO ti = { 0 };
    ti.cbSize = sizeof(TOOLINFO);
    ti.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
    ti.hwnd = hwndParent;
    ti.uId = (UINT_PTR)hwndTool;
    ti.lpszText = const_cast<LPWSTR>(L"This is a tooltip!");
    
    SendMessage(hwndTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&ti);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm not observing its functionality. Are there any other potential solutions that could assist me in resolving this issue?

Comment: See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) Why are you trying to add a tooltip in someone else's process? What is the end goal here?